# When I return to main screen and then active my application again it crashes

Tags: ios, xcode

Here is the line where debugger stops:

```
let ystart = 24+Int((keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top)!)
```

And the bug comment: Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: force unwrapped a nil value.

I would add that the function above is executed every second. Maybe this will clarify the situation a bit.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to figure out what the nil value is? You shouldn’t really force unwrap optional a anyway.

Comment: Yes, I am working on it, but my question is what is going on here. Why it crashes when the app is minimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, it‘s hard to find the real issue but at least we know, keyWindow hasn’t been set yet.

`yourMainWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()` will set the keyWindow. It seems like the failing line is executed before `makeKeyAndVisible()` and therefore it is still `nil`.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622924-keywindow

As mentioned in the comments, always think twice when force-unwrapping an optional, unless you are 100% sure it cannot become `nil`.

Syntactic sugar:
If you need to set a value that depends on an optional, you should also think about a fallback/default if the optional is nil. Using the coalescing operator (`??`) helps to avoid nil-check-if-statements like

```
let ystart = 24+Int(keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? yourDefaultValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed, but I still don't understand the reason behind this problem.
I added simple if statement like if (keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top != nil) {}